# Improving the output of tesseract while detecting phone numbers

Tags: ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I came across the problem of reading phone numbers in images. I tried to detect them in an image using the tesseract, but sometimes it gives me a wrong answer. For example, the number is 8 995 005-81-86, but tesseract gives me 8 995 0005-81-86 as an output. How can I fix it? Maybe binarizing?

---

Code is basic

```py
import pytesseract as pt
from PIL import Image

img = Image.open('1.png')
number = pt.image_to_string(img)

print(number)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvhAq.png

Answer (score 1):

You should pass a black on white text for best results:

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image

img = cv2.imread('kvhAq.png')
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(img, 100, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
im = Image.fromarray(thresh.astype("uint8"))
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(im))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but anyway it sometimes gives a wrong answer

Comment: It depends on the type of images you pass to it. Are they always like in the example you provided?

Comment: Also, try passing different page segmentation modes to pytesseract, see if it helps: `custom_oem_psm_config = r'--psm 6' 
pytesseract.image_to_string(image, config=custom_oem_psm_config)`

Comment: Another tip is to put a larger white border around the image. I've noticed that this can improve detection. Also, you can play with scaling the image larger.

Comment: Photos are all the same

Comment: Try with `--psm 6` and see if that works. Also, @bfris mentioned some good points for recognition.